# How to attach method to method of a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, prototype

example:

```
var A = function (z) {
  this.z = z
}

// attach 1 method

A.prototype.sayHay = function(message) {
  this.message = message
  console.log(message)
}

// attach 2 methods ?????
A.prototype.sayHay.protorype.inReverse = function () {

  // how to avoid the first console.log
  console.log(this.message.split('').reverse().join(''))
}

var b = new A()

b.sayHay('Hola').inReverse()

// this should prints 'aloH'
```

how can I also override the first console.log, because sayHay prints 'Hi' and would returns inReverse 'iH'

E D I T E D - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

how can I do, that by executing only sayHay('Hola') I returns 'Hello' and executing sayHay('Hello').inReverse() returns 'aloH' ?

Comment: problem is sayHi returns nothing....

Comment: Putting a method on the prototype would only work if you were doing `var c = new b.sayHay('Hola'); c.inReverse()`. You just call the method on the return value of `sayHay`, so make it return an object that has this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var A = function (z) {
  this.z = z
}

// attach 1 method

A.prototype.sayHay = function(message) {
  this.message = message;
  return {
    log : function(){console.log(message)},
    rev : function () { console.log(this.message.split('').reverse().join(''))}
  };
}

var b = new A();

b.sayHay('Hola').rev();

// this should prints 'aloH'
```

I have tried to do it in way of closures. Check if you get satisfied to achieve your goal with prototype and closure combination.

Comment: how can I do, that by executing only `sayHay('Hola')` I returns 'Hello' and executing `sayHay('Hello').inReverse()` returns 'aloH' ?

Answer (score 0):

A prototype is used in situations where you create an object using the keyword `new`.

**For Example:**

```
new A().sayHay(...).[Any method from the prototype]
```

So, you can initialize the variable `b` and then execute the function `sayHay` as a constructor:

```
new b.sayHay('Hola').inReverse();
```

```js
var A = function (z) {
  this.z = z
}

// attach 1 method
A.prototype.sayHay = function(message) {
  this.message = message
  //console.log(message);
}

A.prototype.sayHay.prototype.inReverse = function () {
  // how to avoid the first console.log
  console.log(this.message.split('').reverse().join(''))
}

var b = new A();
new b.sayHay('Hola').inReverse();
```

To avoid the first `console.log(message)` you can replace that function at runtime, or remove that line.

Another alternatives is avoiding the second prototyping and return an object:

```js
var A = function (z) {
  this.z = z
}

// attach 1 method
A.prototype.sayHay = function(message) {
  return {
    message: message,
    inReverse: function() {
      console.log(this.message.split('').reverse().join(''));
    }
  }
}

var b = new A();
b.sayHay('Hola').inReverse();
```

Comment: how can I do, that by executing only `sayHay('Hola')` I returns 'Hello' and executing `sayHay('Hello').inReverse()` returns 'aloH' ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using regular classes

```js
class Sayer {
  constructor (message) {
    this.message = message
  }
  
  inReverse() {
    return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
  }
  
  toString() {
    return this.message   
  }
}

class A {
  sayHay(message) {
     return new Sayer(message)
  }
}

console.log(new A().sayHay('Hola').inReverse())
console.log(new A().sayHay('Hola').toString())
```

Comment: how can I do, that by executing only `sayHay('Hola')` I returns 'Hello' and executing `sayHay('Hello').inReverse()` returns 'aloH' ?

Comment: You will have to call `.toString` in this case, or you will have to rely on the method that consumes the Sayer object to call it. You can also name it diffrently, for example `sayHay('Hola').regular()`